# When getting JSON data via NodeJS, how would I update my EJS template via ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ejs

I am calling some APIs using NodeJS and passing them to my EJS template via ExpressJS with this code:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.render('routes/index', {
    plLoopTimes: plLoopTimes,
    pl54Times: pl54Times
})
});
```

In this instance, `plLoopTimes` and `pl54Times` are arrays that have been populated by the JSON that I got from the APIs. In my EJS template, I can simply get the data by running `forEach` on both arrays. The issue that I am facing is when I am starting my node server for the first time, I get fresh data from the APIs, and that fresh data gets fed into the EJS template, but I want to poll the APIs every minute and get fresh data. Now, I do use `setInterval()` on my server-side script to call the API every minute, but I can't figure out how to pass that fresh data into the EJS template without refreshing the entire page, which I don't want to do. I have attempted to create a client-side script to change the `innerHTML` of the element I want to display the data, but if I enter EJS syntax into the script file and pass that into `innerHTML`, the EJS template does not express that syntax and instead, my script just outputs the EJS string into the page. So, does anyone have any suggestions as to how to update the variables from the server-side code into the EJS template on the client-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're doing it wrong. If you need real-time behavior, just use the right tools for that. For this need, I would use [SocketIO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io). If you need old browser support you can do it through simply ajax too, but the benefit of web sockets over ajax is big.

#### Socket.io

This is a simple SocketIO server that send data to all clients every 1 minute.

```
import socketio from 'socket.io';
import { DataRepository } from 'repositories';


const server = http.createServer();
const io = socketio(server);

io.on('connection', (client) => {
  ((interval = 60000, io) => {
    setInterval(() => {
      const data = DataRepository.fetch();
      client.emit('new', data);
    }, interval);
  })();
});
```

All clients just need to create an instance of SocketIO and listen for `new`:

```
const socket = io('http://yoursite.com:port');
socket.on('emit', data => {
  updateView(data);
});

function updateView ({ plLoopTimes, pl54Times}) {
  plLoopTimes.forEach(t => {
    // update things
  });
  pl54Times.forEach(t => {
    // update things
  });
}
```

---

#### Fallback

Another approach -more classic- is for the interval to be defined on the client instead of the server. So, every time that clients request a *new version of the view* the server **render the view to string** and send back to the client.

Here we only need to define a simple route to point a view:

```
router
  .get('/looptimes', (req, res) => {
    const { plLoopTimes, pl54Times } = DataRepository.fetch();
    // render the file 'looptimes.ejs' to string
    const view = ejs.render('looptimes', {
      plLoopTimes, pl54Times
    });
    res.type('.html');
    res.send(view);
  });
```

In the frontend you only need to update the HTML.

Comment: Would I have to create the SocketIO app in Python? Or could I write it in Node, which would be server side?

Comment: You can. There is a [package](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/) for SocketIO in Python. A package for Flask and SocketIO integration is available too.

Answer (score 0):

You've got most of it right, assuming that you aren't running into a race condition where the json isn't actually ready when you receive a request for the page. To access plLoopTimes and pl54Times in your template if you're passing them to res.render() like that you just need to do something like:

```
<%= pl54Times.some.property %>
```

Or if you want to loop over an array of items in that json you can do this:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < arrayName.length; i++) { %>
    <div><%= arrayName[i].some.property.to.display %></div>
<% } %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry.. completely missed the point of the question.. if you want to update the code in real time like that you'll either need to use something like guzgarcia suggested to push the data to the client or use AJAX on the client side to request the new data from your server.